# How to countdown(gieson) with onclick event?

Tags: javascript

The example usage of countdown of [gieson](http://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/countdown/)  as below. It is ok.

```
    <body>
        <script src="countdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript">
                var myCountdown2 = new Countdown({time: 30000, width:200, height:80, rangeHi:"hour"});
        </script>
    </body>
```

[image]

I would like to start countdown when button onclick. But it not ok.

```
<body>
    <script src="countdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript">
        var myCountdown2;
        function startCount() {
            myCountdown2 = new Countdown({time: 30000, width:200, height:80, rangeHi:"hour"});
        }
    </script>
    <input type="button" value="start" onclick="startCount();"/>
</body>
```

[image]

How can I solve it? I don't have `javascript` experience.

Error :

```
Error in parsing value for 'size'.  Declaration dropped.
```

Comment: your code should work fine.. do you get any error in the console?

Comment: @BeNdErR, there is no error. But, as my below image. It cannot count.

Comment: it's working here-> http://jsfiddle.net/BeNdErR/apxavwqq/2/ try moving the scripts import in the <head> tag

Comment: are you using IE? there is some note that Coundown is not compatible with IE

Comment: nope, I use Firefox 30

Answer (score 0):

Try to save `myCountDown2` in global scope.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it and it works fine

```
<body style="background-color:#EDEDED">

<p onClick="return countIt();">Example 1 - Time until April 1, 2016</p>

<!-- START COUNTDOWN -->
<script src="countdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
function countIt(){
var myCountdownTest = new Countdown({
                                    time: 30000, width:200, height:80, rangeHi:"hour"
                                    });


}
</script>
```

Comment: It is like my below image(00:00:00). I already test your code. It does not work.